# How to redirect stderr to /dev/null?

Tags: zsh

I have a little function that allows me to activate my python virtual environment, which for different repos, is sometimes hidden (`.venv`) and sometimes not (`venv`). I'm having trouble suppressing stderr.

This is my little function (it lives in `~/.zshrc`)

```sh
function venv {
    source `ls -a $PWD/*/bin/activate` > /dev/null
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] 
    then
        source `ls -a $PWD/.*/bin/activate` 
    fi
}
```

Only one of `$PWD/*/bin/activate` or `$PWD/.*/bin/activate` will exist, and I'd like to ignore the one that doesn't exist, with no error.

The problem is that this line

```
ls -a $PWD/*/bin/activate 2>&1 /dev/null
```

gives the terminal output

```
zsh: no matches found: /home/jokea/code/FlorA/*/bin/activate
```

My understanding is that `2>&1 /dev/null` should suppress both stderr and stdout. So why isn't it working?

I've tried all the other variations I could find (`>`, `>>`, `&>`, `>&`, etc), but it still prints to terminal. How do I silence all output of my function?

Comment: `zsh: no matches found:` -- that's not `ls: no matches found`; the error is being written _by the shell_ before `ls` starts (as it's the shell responsible for replacing paths with wildcards with things that actually exist on the filesystem); so it's unsurprising that redirecting `ls`'s stderr has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Here 2 things annoy me:

```
ls -a $PWD/*/bin/activate 2>&1 /dev/null
```

The order of redirection is not the right (you redirect the errors in the std output) and `/dev/null` is not prefixed with a stream redirection.

You should first redirect the std output into `/dev/null` and then redirect the std error into the same stream than the std output (that is `/dev/null`) :

```
ls -a $PWD/*/bin/activate > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the stderr redirection may not always be taken into account in zsh wildcard `*` expansions.

A cleaner solution that I commonly use is something like this:

```sh
find . -maxdepth 2 -name activate -type f -print |
  grep /bin/ |
  head -1 |
  while read script
  do source "$script"
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the other answers didn't quite get me there, but based on suggestions from davidxxx and rowboat (thanks for these), I hacked together this:

```
function venv {
    setopt +o nomatch
    ls -a $PWD/.*/bin/activate > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] 
    then
        source `ls -a $PWD/.*/bin/activate` > /dev/null 2>&1 
    else
        ls -a $PWD/*/bin/activate > /dev/null 2>&1
        if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]  
        then   
           source `ls -a $PWD/*/bin/activate` > /dev/null 2>&1  
        else   
           echo "There's no Virtual Environment in $PWD"     
        fi
    fi
}
```

It's admittedly a bit garbagey, but it works. I can now set virtual environments without any errors.

Comment: [Why is checking `$?` to see if a command succeeded or not an antipattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern) -- if you _must_ use `ls`, then consider `if ls -a ...; then ...; else ...`, but it's better to follow the practices given in [BashFAQ #4](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004) (which in this particular case mostly apply to zsh as well).

Answer (score 0):

`2>&1` is one redirection - send fd2 into fd1, effectively sending stderr into stdout.
The second bit, `/dev/null` doesn't do any redirection. You probable meant to redirect stdout to /dev/null, so it should be `> /dev/null`, but as davidxxx mentioned, it should be the other way around (not especially intuitive, imo).

If you just want to redirect one, then just do that:

```
$ (echo stdout; ls /dev/error) 1>/dev/null
ls: /dev/error: No such file or directory
$ (echo stdout; ls /dev/error) 2>/dev/null
stdout
$
```

and, of course, you can do both individually (order doesn't matter since it's /dev/null - I guess it would for a regular file?):

```
$ (echo stdout; ls /dev/error) 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
$
```

You can send stderr(2) into fd1 so it is 'merged' with stuff written to stdout - it looks the same as if you did nothing:

```
$ (echo stdout; ls /dev/error) 2>&1
stdout
ls: /dev/error: No such file or directory
```

but if you put it in a subshell and redirect the resulting stderr(2) to /dev/null, you can see that it is actually part of stdout(1) because nothing changes:

```
$ ((echo stdout; ls /dev/error) 2>&1) 2>/dev/null
stdout
ls: /dev/error: No such file or directory
```

as opposed to:

```
$ ((echo stdout; ls /dev/error) ) 2>/dev/null
stdout
```

So, yeah, you wanted:

```
$ (echo stdout; ls /dev/error) >/dev/null 2>&1
```

which is the same as:

```
$ (echo stdout; ls /dev/error) 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

and, indeed has the same effect as (open /dev/null as fd[2], fd[1] = fd[1]):

```
$ (echo stdout; ls /dev/error) 2>/dev/null 1>&2
```

Maybe a good tip is to think of the low level system calls - I think it might help make the order make sense.

`2>/dev/null` - open /dev/null with file descriptor 2.

`1>&2` - instead of writing to fd 1, write to fd 2 (which has been opened on /dev/null). You could imagine it internally doing `fd[2] = fd[1];`.

Of course, if you don't care about the output, then perhaps you should consider closing them both:

```
$ (echo stdout; ls /dev/error) 1>&- 2>&-
$
```

This could cause problems if you don't close stderr(2) since zsh/echo will try to write to stdout(1), which is closed:

```
$ (echo stdout; ls /dev/error) 1>&-
zsh: write error: bad file descriptor
ls: /dev/error: No such file or directory
```

but it's an option to consider. Works nicely for stderr, it seems (nowhere to complain to).